# File is not uploading using WebElement on Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am using the code below, but the file is not uploading to the browser. Once it clicks on the Browse button, it stuck there:-

```
@Test (priority = 7)
public void uploadFCLetterOnlu() throws InterruptedException
{
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("btnUploadfile")).click();

      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("btnBrowseFiles")).click();

      WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("btnBrowseFiles"));

      String filePath = "C:\\Users\\sshre\\OneDrive\\Documents\\TestFiles\\GuaranteedPricing\\FC53_ADC_MXD_AADC_LTR.zip";

      upload.sendKeys(filePath);;
      Thread.sleep(10000);

      driver.findElement(By.id("upload_Done_button")).click();  

      String jobId = "00028977";
      Assert.assertEquals(jobId, "00028977");
      System.out.println(jobId + " is present in the page");
}
```

Comment: What error you getting?